# Como "zerar" a outra linha SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma consulta que retorna para mim o quanto determinado cliente comprou de um certo produto.

O problema está no item(produto) pois o mesmo tem mais de uma característica que causa duplicidade no valor que ele comprou no geral.

Na consulta é feita a junção com a mesma tabela pois preciso saber quanto ele comprou no geral em relação, por exemplo, a 2018 e 2019.

```
  OINV - tabela mãe onde pego o código do cliente.
  INV1 - tabela filha da OINV onde fica o valor das vendas.
  [DBO].[ItemCaracteristica] - View que retorna as características deste item.
```

```
DECLARE
        @DATA INT

SET @DATA = 2019
SELECT 
       TB.Cliente,
       TB.CODIGO,
       TB.Descricao,
       tb.Caracteristica,
       TB.ANOAnterior,
       TB.ValorAnterior,
       TB.ANOATUAL,
       [ValorAtual] = SUM(TB.ValorAtual)


FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            [Cliente] = T0.CardCode,
            [CODIGO] = T4.item,
            [Descricao] = T4.Descricao,
            [Caracteristica] = t4.caracteristica,
            [ANOAnterior] = YEAR(T1.DocDate), 
            [ValorAnterior] = T3.LineTotal,
            [AnoAtual] = YEAR(T0.DocDate), 
            [ValorAtual] = T2.LineTotal
            --CASE WHEN YEAR(T1.DocDate) IS NULL THEN 100 ELSE SUM(T0.DocTotal) / SUM(T1.DocTotal) END,
            --[CALCULO] = IIF(YEAR(T1.DocDate) IS NULL, 100 , SUM(T2.LineTotal) / SUM(T3.LineTotal))
        FROM OINV T0
        LEFT JOIN OINV T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode AND YEAR(T1.DocDate) = @DATA -1
        INNER JOIN INV1 T2 ON T0.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry AND T2.ItemCode = '1000'
        LEFT JOIN  INV1 T3 ON T1.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry AND T3.ItemCode = '1000'
        INNER JOIN [DBO].[ItemCaracteristica] T4 ON T2.ItemCode = T4.Item
        WHERE YEAR(T0.DocDate) = @DATA
        AND T0.CANCELED = 'N'
--GROUP BY T0.Cardcode,T2.LineTotal, T3.LineTotal,YEAR(T1.DocDate), YEAR(T0.DocDate) 
) AS TB 
GROUP BY tb.Cliente, TB.CODIGO, TB.Descricao, tb.Caracteristica,
         TB.ANOAnterior, TB.AnoAtual, ValorAnterior
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode concatenar  a característica, assim ele vai retornar apenas uma linha.

Comment: A versão do SQL management studio é 2014 ele não aceita essa função

Comment: O valor correto seria 17,50 uma vez e não duas como mostra na imagem que anexei. seria tipo para zerar a outra linha.

Answer (score 1):

Para mim não está ocorrendo duplicidade, pois na coluna "Característica" as informações exibidas são diferentes. Duplicidade seria se todo o conteúdo da linha fosse o mesmo. No caso, é necessário retirar a coluna "Característica" do resultado para garantir que para cada CLIENTE/CODIGO haja uma única linha.

Raramente DISTINCT é a forma correta de se eliminar repetições; quase sempre é algum erro na cláusula FROM, nas junções; ou faltou coluna na junção ou tem tabela a mais.

Quando se programa em SQL é necessário ficar atento para que os predicados sejam *sargable*. Detalhes no artigo “[Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)”.

Eis sugestão de código que utiliza predicados *sargable*:

```
-- código #1
-- informe o ano a pesquisar
declare @ANO int;
set @ANO = 2019;

--
declare @Inicio_ano date, @Final_ano date, 
        @Inicio_ano_anterior date, @Final_ano_anterior date;
set @Inicio_ano= datefromparts (@ANO, 1, 1);
set @Final_ano= datefromparts (@ANO, 12, 31);
set @Inicio_ano_anterior= dateadd (year, -1, @Inicio_ano);
set @Final_ano_anterior= dateadd (year, -1, @Final_ano);

--
SELECT [Cliente] = T0.CardCode,
       [CODIGO] = T2.ItemCode,
       [Descricao] = T4.Descricao,
       [ANOAnterior] = (@ANO -1), 
       [ValorAnterior] = sum (coalesce (T3.LineTotal, 0)),
       [AnoAtual] = @ANO, 
       [ValorAtual] = sum (T2.LineTotal)

  from OINV as T0
       left join OINV as T1 on T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode 
       inner join INV1 as T2 on T0.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry 
       left join INV1 as T3 on T1.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry
       outer apply (SELECT top (1) T.Descricao
                      from dbo.ItemCaracteristica as T 
                      where T2.ItemCode = T.Item) as T4

  where T0.DocDate between @Inicio_ano and @Final_ano
        and T0.CANCELED = 'N'
        and (T1.CardCode is null or 
             (T1.DocDate between @Inicio_ano_anterior and @Final_ano_anterior))
        and T2.ItemCode = '1000'
        and (T3.DocEntry is null or T3.ItemCode = '1000')

  group by T0.Cardcode,T2.ItemCode, T4.Descricao;
```

---

No código original do autor percebe-se que as tabelas OINV e INV1 aparecem duas vezes; se o volume de linhas a ler nos dois anos for elevado, é melhor alterar para ler uma única vez cada tabela, agrupar também por ano e fazer o pivô com o resultado. Detalhes no artigo “[Alas & Pivôs](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)”.

Comment: O resultado da consulta que alteraste foi null.

Comment: O que significa NULL: nenhuma linha? alguma coluna com NULL?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
        @DATA INT

SET @DATA = 2019
SELECT 
       TB.Cliente,
       TB.CODIGO,
       TB.Descricao,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tb.Caracteristica ORDER BY tb.Caracteristica SEPARATOR '-'),
       TB.ANOAnterior,
       TB.ValorAnterior,
       TB.ANOATUAL,
       [ValorAtual] = SUM(TB.ValorAtual)


FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            [Cliente] = T0.CardCode,
            [CODIGO] = T4.item,
            [Descricao] = T4.Descricao,
            [Caracteristica] = t4.caracteristica,
            [ANOAnterior] = YEAR(T1.DocDate), 
            [ValorAnterior] = T3.LineTotal,
            [AnoAtual] = YEAR(T0.DocDate), 
            [ValorAtual] = T2.LineTotal
            --CASE WHEN YEAR(T1.DocDate) IS NULL THEN 100 ELSE SUM(T0.DocTotal) / SUM(T1.DocTotal) END,
            --[CALCULO] = IIF(YEAR(T1.DocDate) IS NULL, 100 , SUM(T2.LineTotal) / SUM(T3.LineTotal))
        FROM OINV T0
        LEFT JOIN OINV T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode AND YEAR(T1.DocDate) = @DATA -1
        INNER JOIN INV1 T2 ON T0.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry AND T2.ItemCode = '1000'
        LEFT JOIN  INV1 T3 ON T1.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry AND T3.ItemCode = '1000'
        INNER JOIN [DBO].[ItemCaracteristica] T4 ON T2.ItemCode = T4.Item
        WHERE YEAR(T0.DocDate) = @DATA
        AND T0.CANCELED = 'N'
--GROUP BY T0.Cardcode,T2.LineTotal, T3.LineTotal,YEAR(T1.DocDate), YEAR(T0.DocDate) 
) AS TB 
GROUP BY tb.Cliente, TB.CODIGO, TB.Descricao,
         TB.ANOAnterior, TB.AnoAtual, ValorAnterior
```

Se eu entendi o que voce precisa seria isso, testa ai

Comment: Não consigo usar o GROUP_CONCAT() por causa da versão do meu SQLServer